# Are Microsoft Graph calls to PATCH (update) a list items fields case sensitive?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When attempting to call the Update item API endpoint on the Microsoft graph, the field names appear to be case sensitive. The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http does not indicate this.  Are the calls to the /fields endpoint case sensitive?

I am trying to update a single line text field named "Status" (both the internal name and the display name are "Status" (upper case initial S).  When calling the /v1.0/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/item{id}/fields endpoint from Graph Explorer with the following the call fails:

```
{
    "status":"testing"
}
```

The following is returned.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Field 'status' is not recognized",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "8700ae5d-f2e5-4138-891a-f980630aa7d1",
            "date": "2020-05-02T15:30:14"
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the body of the PATCH request is the following:

```
{
    "Status":"testing"
}
```

the call succeeds and returns the item being updated, all fields and a correctly updated "Status field.

Given that I am calling the API directly from C# (using HttpClient and NOT using an SDK yet so FieldValueSet is not an option here) and using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver for JsonSerializerSettings with the following code:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, $"{graphEndpoint}{version}{uri}");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
{
    request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}

var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

and the body is always camel cased and fails. Is this a bug? and if not, what is considered the better practice for this since most things I have tried (JObject and others) seem like really back compensation hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a final answer, I am using the following.

Within the class I define a default and camel case resolver.

```
private readonly JsonSerializerSettings camelCaseJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
private readonly JsonSerializerSettings defaultJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() };
```

Within the method that makes the call I am simply choosing which settings to use based on the Http method and the uri containing SharePoint for now.

```
if (body != null && (method != HttpMethod.Get || method != HttpMethod.Delete))
{
   if ((method != HttpMethod.Post) && (uri.Contains("/sites/"))) 
   {
      // Serialize the body to be pascal cased due to SP Bug
      payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, defaultJsonSettings);
   }
   else
   {
     // Serialize the body with camelCasing 
     payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, camelCaseJsonSettings);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a known issue with SharePoint APIs for [quite some time](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/06/field-names-in-rest-query-are-case.html). There is a related bug in [SharePoint Graph APIs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4250), specifically that Graph camel cases the column names.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Then the question is, if this is a known bug is there any recommended way to address the issue or ETA for a fix?

Comment: I'm not aware of any workaround or an ETA but since this has been around since at least 2012, I wouldn't expect a near-term fix.

Comment: Thanks again Marc.  I included my work around below for anyone looking for an answer.  Appreciate the response!